# I want to compare 2 columns for corresponding data

Tags: microsoft-excel

Match is useful for number comparison but i want to compare letters, please advise.

please note that row number may not be matching data should match.
i got it for numbers =MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$6,0)
but i want match letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can match for both letters and numbers with the same formula:

[image]

Gives the row in which the letter **S** is found.